# How to enable plugin in Chrome Browser through capabilities using Web Driver?

Tags: google-chrome, web, webdriver

While starting Chrome Browser through my script I want to enable the plugins automatically.

How can I do this using Chrome Options or is there any other way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Pythonic one for remote driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--always-authorize-plugins=true')
capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='http://hub_address/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

and for local one

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--always-authorize-plugins=true')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: @PriyankaAgarwal, what extensions do tou want to launch? The ones that are enabled in you 'common' Chrome?

Comment: thanks Alexander ..

but can you please elaborate what I should place in "/path/to/extension.crx" .
Actually I want to enable the plugins automatically when the Chrome Browser is launched .To do so manually I need to navigate to settings--> Show Advanced Settings--> Content Settings -> JavaScript->Click the radio button Allow All sites to run JavaScript...
. I want to do this through my script by setting the Capabilities .

Comment: when I execute my script I get the error message " The following plugins were blocked on this page " . I need to click on the "Always allow plugins..." and then click on the Done button manually. i want to set this through capabilities ... so that this plugins are enabled autocratically whenever the Chrome browser is launched.Plz help

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood your question first. Thought you were talking about launching chrome extensions. Gonna edit my answer in a moment

Comment: thank you so much for the response.. I will  try this and will update you soon

Comment: Hi..can you please tell me how this can be done through through Java and I am using Web driver for Automation .